# Block diagonalization with similiarity transform using invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, block-matrices, invariant-subspace

How can I show that if the full n-vector space V can be written as a direct sum of subspaces V_i for i=1,... k, such that all V_i are invariant subspaces of diagonalizable matrix A, I can block diagonalize A through a similarity transform

A_blkdiag=(S^-1)AS

where the columns of S contain linearly independent vectors that span first V_1, all the way up to V_k?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I think I actually got it. Examining A×S, we can note that for the resulting matrix, the column indices  corresponding to those of S associated with the vectors spanning V_i can each be written as a linear combination of vectors from V_i from these subspaces being invariant subspaces of A. Then, we can rewrite this as A×S=S×D, where D is the matrix containing the coefficients on the linear combinations of the spanning vectors in S. Noting the specified ordering of columns in S, we can note that D is a block diagonal matrix of coefficients. Then, we have (S^-1)×A×S=(S^-1)×S×D=D, and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. Examining A×S, we can note that for the resulting matrix, the column indices corresponding to those of S associated with the vectors spanning V_i can each be written as a linear combination of vectors from V_i, since these subspaces are all invariant subspaces of A. Then, we can rewrite this as A×S=S×D, where D is the matrix containing the coefficients on the linear combinations of the spanning vectors in S. Noting the specified ordering of columns in S, we can note that D is a block diagonal matrix of coefficients. Then, we have (S^-1)×A×S=(S^-1)×S×D=D, and so lemma proved.